# the type org.controlsfx.control.CheckComboBox is not accessible | javafx

Tags: java, javafx

I'm working on a JavaFX program and I need [`CheckComboBox`](https://github.com/controlsfx/controlsfx/blob/791365178119238940942c2cc5003e4bd166d346/controlsfx/src/main/java/org/controlsfx/control/CheckComboBox.java). I downloaded different `controlsfx` files and added them to

```
Libraries -> ModulePath and Libraries -> Classpath
```

but it also tells me that

```
org.controlsfx.control.CheckComboBox
```

is not accessible. I wasted a lot of time with this and still haven't found an answer; does anyone know how to fix it?

[image]

Comment: I don't recognize the IDE, but you might review [*Getting Started with JavaFX*](https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/).

Comment: I can't believe I didn't realize it .....adding "requires org.controlsfx.controls;" in my module-info.java helped me...thx @jewelsea !

Answer (score 0):

ControlsFX has a [module-info](https://github.com/controlsfx/controlsfx/blob/master/controlsfx/src/main/java/module-info.java), so I think you should have it on the module path not the class path.

You will also need to require the module (`org.controlsfx.controls`) in your application’s module info, if you have one, or add to your `--add-module` VM argument if you don’t have a module info. See a tutorial on the Java module system if you don’t understand.

I also advise using a build tool like maven with a [controlsfx](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.controlsfx/controlsfx/11.1.1) dependency.